# EasyMock unexpected method call

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, easymock

I can't work out how to setup the expectation of a call to a mock class. Here is the JUnit test:

```
public class AfkTest extends TestCase {
private AfkPlayerManager manager;
private Player player;
private Set<AfkPlayer> afkPlayers;


public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();

    manager = new AfkPlayerManager();
    player = EasyMock.createMock(Player.class);
    afkPlayers = new HashSet<AfkPlayer>();
}

public void tearDown() {
}

public void testNotifyOfAfkPlayerSuccess() {
    AfkPlayer afkPlayer = new AfkPlayer();
    afkPlayer.setPlayer(player);
    afkPlayer.setReason("TEST REASON");
    afkPlayers.add(afkPlayer);

    List<Player> onlinePlayers = new ArrayList<Player>();
    onlinePlayers.add(player);
    onlinePlayers.add(player);

    EasyMock.expect(player.getDisplayName()).andReturn("TEST PLAYER");

    player.sendMessage("Â§9TEST PLAYERÂ§b is AFK. [TEST REASON]");
    EasyMock.expectLastCall().times(1);

    //activate the mock
    EasyMock.replay(player);    

    assertTrue(manager.notifyOfAfkPlayer(onlinePlayers, afkPlayer));

    //verify call to sendMessage is made or not
    EasyMock.verify(player);
}
```

}

And the method that I am testing:

```
   public class AfkPlayerManager implements Manager {

    public boolean notifyOfAfkPlayer(Collection<Player> onlinePlayers, AfkPlayer afkPlayer) {

        if (afkPlayer == null) {

            return false;
        }

        String message = ChatColor.BLUE + afkPlayer.getPlayer().getDisplayName();
        message += ChatColor.AQUA + " is AFK.";

        if (afkPlayer.getReason().length() > 0) {

            message += " [" + afkPlayer.getReason() + "]";
        }


        if (onlinePlayers != null && onlinePlayers.size() > 1) {

            int notified = 0;

            for (Player onlinePlayer : onlinePlayers) {

                onlinePlayer.sendMessage(message);
                notified++;
            }

            if (notified > 0) {

                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Why is this giving me the AssertionError:

> java.lang.AssertionError:    Unexpected method call
>   Player.sendMessage("§9TEST PLAYER§b is AFK. [TEST REASON]"):
>       Player.sendMessage("Â§9TEST PLAYERÂ§b is AFK. [TEST REASON]"): expected: 1, actual: 0     at
>   org.easymock.internal.MockInvocationHandler.invoke(MockInvocationHandler.java:44)
>     at
>   org.easymock.internal.ObjectMethodsFilter.invoke(ObjectMethodsFilter.java:94)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.sendMessage(Unknown Source)    at
>   crm.afk.AfkPlayerManager.notifyOfAfkPlayer(AfkPlayerManager.java:33)
>     at crm.test.AfkTest.testNotifyOfAfkPlayerSuccess(AfkTest.java:84)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:176)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:141)   at
>   junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)     at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)  at
>   junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)   at
>   junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)   at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:252)     at
>   junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:247)     at
>   org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)

Answer (score 0):

The expected and actual are different.

Expected: `Â§9TEST PLAYERÂ§b is AFK. [TEST REASON]`
Actual:   `§9TEST PLAYER§b is AFK. [TEST REASON]`

The Â at the beginning is missing. So it fails as it should.